# Debugging a badblock case, advice?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-blocks

Everything started with Windows failures. It was impatiently kicking some BSOD out because of missing dlls (there is a question here, which I basically solved).
I then discovered that the dlls were actually missing, or better 0 byte files.
I have started suspecting some block corruption and I went to two old friends, badblocks and smartmontools. Badblocks starts analyzing the Windows partition and then hangs my whole machine at around 1.68%. Luckily, I can CTRL-C and end it, with the following report (and blocks in the output file).

badblocks:

```
Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 102399999
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: ^C^C^C^C^Cquiy11:10 elapsed. (16/0/0 errors)
^C^X  1.63% done, 11:27 elapsed. (16/0/0 errors)

Interrupted at block 1669692

Interrupt caught, cleaning up
```

The other friend, smartmontools, is actually more friendly than usual.

smartmontools:

```
BlockquoteError 333 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1611 hours (67 days + 3 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
40 51 00 28 34 a7 02  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x02a73428 = 44512296

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
25 00 00 00 34 a7 e2 00      02:29:09.041  READ DMA EXT
27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      02:29:09.039  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      02:29:09.038  IDENTIFY DEVICE
ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00      02:29:09.037  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      02:29:09.037  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
```

My question would be now, how do I proceed? Can I try to write on the blocks and attempt a recovery of the blocks. Would be a badblocks -yacc enough?
The rest of the hard disk seems fine, I know that I can run into troubles but I have backups. I would like to avoid reinstalling Windows but I don't see how at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNC error could happens to be soft-bad error.
In that case you have two option:

1) make a new backup (I would suggest [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) as it makes exect copy of disk/partition) ,  then run badblocks in destructive read-write mode and see what it result. If it shows no bad-block - then restore your image back.

2) You could try approach from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/642670/tool-to-read-all-blocks-from-hdd-and-write-it-back), but as your attempt to run badblocks in non-destructive read-write mode hang - this option will not work for you.

Also you could have hard-bad error. Also you mention that you seams to not have problem with rest of disk. In that case you have two other two option (to avoid reinstall of OS):

3) buy a new disk of same or bigger size and do cloning to it. I would suggest [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddrescue/) or you could use Clonezilla or other cloning soft.

4) You could do repartition of your existed disk in such way that bad area is out of any partition. In that case nothing would request that area. Same time as you say that badblocks hang - it seams that area is rather big. To find out bad area location I would suggest to run ddrescue with logging enabled. It effectively skips bad blocks. Then in log file you will exect location of bad area.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixing bad blocks. You can ignore them, skip them, "repair them" by marking them as bad, attempting to move the data else where... etc.. I would cut your losses, move everything off and replace the drive. Generally when blocks start to fail it gets worse before it gets better. Not a chance I would take.