# Bootup "Operating System not found" Error?

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio

I have a new Sony Vaio sve151J13L laptop.Every time I start the laptop first the Sony Vaio logo appears and then the screen goes black and an error message appears "Operating System not found". In fact this stage is not the only problem, I cannot get on BOIS, F2, F8, F12, do not work!!

Comment: I don't think it says *that*. Is there anything else on the screen? At the bottom, maybe? (btw, you probably don't have BIOS but [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface))

Comment: https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/30721

Comment: @grnostaj Operating System Not Found is a common Windows error message.

Comment: @JanDoggen yes it is, but the question was [edited](http://superuser.com/revisions/685270/1).

Answer (score 0):

From [Sony Vaio UEFI BIOS Windows 7 8](http://www.overclock.net/t/1321845/sony-vaio-uefi-bios-windows-7-8):

> I made this post because I just spent 3 hours trying tofind out how to boot into the BIOS / UEFI on my sister's new Sony Vaio.The solution is really easy but not a single google search suggested pressing that stupid button.
>
> Here goes:
>
> Anyone who has a Sony VAIO notebook with a UEFI BIOS and can't seem to get into it..Power down your laptop and press the "assist" button.That's it.
>
> Should point out to try F2 or F3 first to get into the UEFI BIOS. If that doesn't work then try the assist button.

Comment: If you're the same Sam who posted the question, please register on this site, and contact the team to have your accounts associated. Thanks (http://superuser.com/contact)

Comment: But does this solve your "Operating System not found" message? Please add to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Operating system not found" is often a sign of damaged sectors underlying critical OS files. You should use a non-OS specific sector recovery tool that you can boot from CD/USB.

I have described some of these [here](https://superuser.com/questions/642670/tool-to-read-all-blocks-from-hdd-and-write-it-back/642822#642822)