# HDD Current_Pending_Sector attribute going up and down

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, bad-blocks

I have Western Digital Caviar Black drive (model WD2002FAEX-007BA0).
System is running Linux Mint 14. Filesystem on drive ext4.

Recently I've got some i/o errors on one of the files. Then I've checked smart and saw Current_Pending_Sector count go up. (few sectors, don't remember exact number)

I've copied all information to another disk and tried to do several badblocks check (in read-only and non destructive mode) using following commands

```
fsck -vck /dev/sdb1 and fsck -vcck /dev/sdb1
```

After each scan it reported more and more badblocks. **Current_Pending_Sector** went as high as 90. Since drive is 2TB, each full scan takes up to day to complete. So I decided to selectively scan only block ranges with badblocks on that partition.

```
badblocks -b 4096 -sv -p 2 /dev/sdb1 48696066 48674506
```

after few scans badblock reported  more that 1K errors. Then I've decided to wipe whole partition and do destructive write test with badblocks on whole drive.

```
badblocks -wsv ~/bb-sdb.txt /dev/sdb
```

but badblocks didn't reported any errors, and magically **Current_Pending_Sector** went to zero.

Full SMART status available [here](http://pastebin.com/sH1NASrN)(pastebin)

Question is why **Current_Pending_Sector** went to zero? (I understand meaning of pending sector, but question is rather why it went down after full destructive write scan)
And can I still trust this drive?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you had most likely result of Silent Data Degradation
Through using "badblocks" regulary I am trying to [resolve](https://superuser.com/questions/642670/tool-to-read-all-blocks-from-hdd-and-write-it-back) it. 
From my expirience some disks more affected to Silent Data Degradation and some less.
Here is some reading regarding [Read Instability](http://www.deepspar.com/wp.html)

Answer (score 0):

To answer original question:
No, I should have not trust that drive anymore. 
Couple months after described problem drive died. It became undetectable by system. Luckily, I had full drive backup, so no data was lost. 
Second drive (exact same model and capacity) still works with no problems